# modelling radar system for image generation

Tags: computer-vision, python, radar, radio, programming

I am trying to find or derive some model for radar using python and blender which should hopefully create a simulation of what a radar image of the blender environment would look like.

I have been reading a lot of papers but am still struggling. I understand the concept of

> transmitter sends out radio wave -> wave is reflected off of surface -> antenna receives returning signal -> received data processed to make 2d image

but I can't figure out how to implement it myself, or even if it is feasible given my inexperience with signal processing.

I see lots of descriptions for things like radar cross section, range, reflected power, but cant find much on formulae that might model the reflection, receiving, and  algorithms that might help turn the results from the previous step into 2d image information.

Comment: Hi and a heartily welcom to this site. I think you're working on something tremendously interesting, but as this is a Q&A site, we *really* need you to ask a *question*. That also serves as a help to you – formulating a question makes it necessary to consider what you'd need to understand in a first step to go ahead. Like you're stating this now, you're expecting us to write a book on radar signal processing – which you'll understand is a bit broad for the format of this site.

Comment: @MarcusMüller hi, thanks for the response. should i edit this question or post a new one if i come up with a more specific, easier to answer, question?

Comment: It looks like you are looking for a complete tutorial which we wouldn’t offer here; as Marcus stated this is best for concise and specific Q&A, once you have done sufficient research on your own. I recommend deleting this question entirely and then asking questions to help you along after you have done your own research (in other words avoid asking questions that you can answer by googling yourself or reading up on it at Wikipedia but rather show your work, insightful questions and what you are struggling with and we can help you with that!). Have a great holiday and we hope to see you soon.